# Create metric in MicroStrategy that returns Min Date

Tags: rdbms, olap, microstrategy

I have a database that maintains history of item receipts. I would like to create a Metric that returns the first receipt date corresponding to an item. The challenge I'm having is that null values are possible and converted to date 1/1/1900 (on a given date the item existed but had not been received). How can I return the next date in value list if first date is 1/1/1900?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want if you build the metric with:

- A filter to ignore your specified "NULL-Date"
- Level: Set grouping to "Beginning Fact" for your date attribute
- Use min(date attribute) as formula

Here is my test-version of the metric, "Ttime" is the date-attribute

`Min(Ttime) {~+, <|Ttime+} <[date filter]; @2; ->`

Definition of the "date filter" used (really only a simple "> [NULL-SURROGATE]"):

`Ttime (ID) Greater than 1/1/1900`